# Does AngularJS work with IE 9 and Sharepoint?

Tags: iframe, angularjs, ie

I have investigated far and wide for an explanation and solution to this problem, but now put my hands up and ask for your help!

On my SP 2013 cloud-based site, I have Home.aspx with a CEWP, which opens the index.html file containing AngularJS app (v1.4.2) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testLabApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Store search and activity booking tool</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/testlab/Webparts/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/testlab/Webparts/js/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/testlab/Webparts/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/testlab/Webparts/testLabApp/testLabApp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/testlab/Webparts/testLabApp/extfunctions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/testlab/Webparts/testLabApp/dal.js"></script>
    <link href="/sites/testlab/Webparts/testLabApp/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content" ng-view>
        <!-- View content -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I used Windows 7 with IE 11 for development, but then discovered that under Emulation for IE9 nothing appears on the Home.aspx page. Non errors in the console and I cannot determine via debugging where it is going wrong.

So, my first question is whether anyone has had success with SP 2013, Angularjs (any version) and IE 9. If so, what are your browser security settings?

IFRAMEs
Secondly, I have tried using an IFRAME on the Home.aspx calling index.aspx (renamed from index.html) and with a Page View WP (same as IFRAME).

This only partially works, because although the app displays content and reads from SP Lists with REST, it cannot write to the lists - Security Violation.

Also, I cannot get the user's login name using _spPageContextInfo from within the IFRAME.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Have you tried using the `data-` prefix on the angular attributes, so it says `data-ng-view` instead of just `ng-view`?

Comment: @DanielZiga No, I have not. What does the data- mean?

Comment: It's just a attribute prefix that is recommended to try as some "older" browsers might not approve custom attributes without that prefix.

Comment: Similarly, should I change all ng-... refs to data-ng-..., i.e. ng-include, ng-scope, ng-repeat, etc. ?

Comment: I changed all ng- refs to data-ng- in all HTML files and still the same problem. Does not work in IE9. (Note. This is not using IFRAME solution.) - thanks for suggestion @DanielZiga

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (Angular App in SP, which was not working with IE9, but all other browser).

Delete the `ng-app="testLabApp"` from the `html` tag and insert a separate `div` (after body) with `ng-app`. That was working for me with IE9 in SP.

Comment: This should do the trick. I've got a provider hosted app (mvc5) and had to put ng-app on <body> element. On <html> element it didn't work.